# How to get checkbox click event on change

Tags: checkbox, angular5, angular-material2, angular-changedetection

how to get checkbox click event on the change in angular 5
i have used the following code

html code

```
  <mat-accordion>
         <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                option
              </mat-expansion-panel-header> 
              <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index"
              value="option" [checked]="options.indexOf(option) >= 0"
                               (change)="updateCheckedOptions(option, $event)">  {{option}}</mat-checkbox>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
```

ts code

```
initOptionsMap() {
  for (let x = 0; x<this.order.options.length; x++) {
      this.optionsMap[this.options[x]] = true;
  }
}
updateCheckedOptions(option, event) {
  this.optionsMap[option] = event.target.checked;
}
updateOptions() {
  for(const x in this.optionsMap) {
      if(this.optionsMap[x]) {
          this.optionsChecked.push(x);
      }
  }
  this.options = this.optionsChecked;
  this.optionsChecked = [];
}
```

and i am geting error as

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

please help me with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event` object doesn't have a `target` property (this is what the error is telling you).

What you are looking for is most likely the `checked` property of the event object itself, so you can modify your function like this:

```
updateCheckedOptions(option, event) {
  this.optionsMap[option] = event.checked;
}
```

Comment: @bugs: would this `event.checked` work correctly with custom `checkbox` where the `ngModel` is being passed dynamically? I'm facing [this kind of issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161220/custom-checkbox-why-ngmodule-cant-get-update-the-boolean-checkbox-status) and just can't figure out the exact reason.